# Scanning from files

Tags: c, enums, unions, scanf

I am currently trying to scan a single line in from a file but having a snag at strings.
This is the example line my professor told me to work on.

```
enum status{MEM,PREP,TRAV}
union type { double int day, char* title, float cost}

13953 P 12 26 2011 1 5 2012 2 A 3.30 249.00 A 2.0 148.00 MEM Cuba Christmas 3 0 2 Sierra Del Rosario, Cuba
```

I'm fine with everything accept at the point (MEM Cuba Christmas) when I'm scanning it in from a FILE. I read the first part of the data just using `fscanf()`, but MEM is a enumerated type with a union type that dictates the following input. My problem is with the syntax of the scanning. I tried using getline starting at MEM but I hit snags with the tokenizing since the city / country can have spaces. Not sure what other scans to use I was looking at `sscanf()` but wasn't sure if it works with files.

UPDATED:

```
int main(void);
{
 int m, length = 100;
 char *word, file_name[100];
 FILE *file_point
 printf("Please enter file name with .txt extension:");
 scanf("%s", file_name);
 file_point = fopen(file_name,"r");

  while (fscanf(file_point, "%d", &m) != EOF)
  {

  temp.dest_code = m;
  fscanf(file_point, " %c %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
     &temp.area_code,
     &temp.Smonth, &temp.Sday, &temp.Syear,
     &temp.Emonth, &temp.Eday, &temp.Eyear,
     &temp.leg_num);
  for (n=0; n < temp.leg_num; n++)
    {
      fscanf(file_point," %c %f %f",
         &temp.tleg[n].travel_type,
         &temp.tleg[n].travel_time,
         &temp.tleg[n].cost);
    }
  fscanf(file_point," %d %d %d ",
     &temp.adult,
     &temp.child,
     &temp.infant);


  temp_name = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
  getline (&temp_name, &length, file_point);

  word = strtok(temp_name, ",");

  temp.dest_name=(char *)malloc(strlen(word)+1);
  strcpy(temp.dest_name, word);

  word = strtok(NULL, ",");

  temp.dest_country=(char *)malloc(strlen(word)+1);
  strcpy(temp.dest_country,word2);

  printf("name:%s country:%s\n", temp.dest_name, temp.dest_country);
      printf("adult:%d , child:%d , infant:%d \n", temp.adult, temp.child, temp.infant);

   }
}
```

This was the code I was using as a base that I came up with but not sure how to handle the enumerated and union. I was thinking of doing something like:

```
getline(&status, &length, file_point);
```

but how do I convert string to integer or float?

Comment: Oh yea forgot to mention that I'm scanning this single line in from a file

Comment: could you post some code, to show us what have you tried to do since now?

Comment: The `enum` needs a semi-colon at the end.  The `union` also needs a semi-colon at the end, and the commas need to be semi-colons.  However, if you've got your code compiling, then the trouble is that you did not copy and paste your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem properly (I'm not sure I do), then you face the problem of seeing 'MEM' (or 'PREP' or 'TRAV') as a string in the input, and you have to understand how to handle the following data.  The `enum` suggests that you might want to convert the string MEM to the value of MEM in the enumeration.

It is hard to fully automate such a conversion.  It would be simplest simply to recognize the strings and decide what to do based on the string:

```
if (strcmp(found_string, "MEM") == 0)
    ...do the MEM stuff...
else if (strcmp(found_string, "PREP") == 0)
    ...do the PREP stuff...
else if (strcmp(found_string, "TRAV") == 0)
    ...do the TRAV stuff...
else
    ...report unknown type code...
```

However, you can create a structure to handle the conversion from string to enumeration value.

```
struct StateConv
{
     const char *string;
     enum state  number;
};

static struct StateConv converter[] =
{
    { "MEM",  MEM  },
    { "PREP", PREP },
    { "TRAV", TRAV },
};
enum { NUM_STATECONV = sizeof(converter) / sizeof(converter[0]) };

enum state state_conversion(const char *string)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATECONV; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(string, converter[i].string) == 0)
            return(converter[i].number);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to find conversion for %s\n", string);
    exit(1);
}
```

You need a better error handling strategy than 'exit on error'.

Your scanning code will need to read the word, and then call `state_conversion()`.  Then depending on what you get back, you can read the remaining (following) data in the correct way for the state you were given.

Comment: ah okay I was getting a lot of errors trying to treat it as a string

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that in the way you are trying. MEM in your file is a string type, you need to parse it like you parse a string and then set the value of your enum according to that string. 
For example, when you want to parse your status type (MEM,PREP,TRAV):

```
char typeBuffer[6];
fscanf(file_point,"%5s",typeBuffer);
```

Then manually compare the content of typeBuffer:

```
status stat;
if (strcmp(typeBuffer, "MEM") == 0){
     stat = MEM;
}
```

The conversion between string type and enum cannot be implicit.

Comment: The `typeBuffer` is one too small for reading 'PREP' or 'TRAV' - you need at least 5 there, and probably more to allow for mistakes.  It would not be a bad idea to use `"%5s"` and dimension 6; that allows you to reject 'TRAVEL' without overflowing the variable.